# Photo manager that organises by folder structure

Tags: software-recommendation, folder, photo-management

I have my pictures very well organized on the harddisk, in this structure:

- Pictures

  - Canon

    - Holiday 2010
  - Sony

    - Graduation 2000
  - Other Albums

    - Steves Holiday 2010 Album

Thus, I have a main folder that holds all my pictures, and within a lot of folders with subfolders of at least 2 levels (device & album name).

I used Picasa to organize my pictures on Windows, now on Ubuntu I would like to use a more native application than running Picasa on Wine.
There is a lot of applications out there, but none of these seems to be able to import all my pictures and organize it in the hierarchy I arranged them in with folders and subfolder like Picasa does it.

Is there an application, preferably for the GNOME desktop that can do this?

Comment: This was very useful to me. I was using ROX-Filer + feh and it was just tedious to rename files one by one. digikam helps a lot. If one of the answers solved your need, perhaps you could select a "winning" answer and extend your question with the factors which made you pick it?

Answer (score 5):

[**digiKam**](http://www.digikam.org/) ([Click to Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/digikam))

[image]

> digiKam is an image organizer and editor using KDE Platform. It runs on most known desktop environments and window managers if needed libraries are installed. It supports all major image file formats, and can organize collections of photographs in directory-based albums, or dynamic albums by date, timeline, or by tags. Users can also add captions and ratings to their images, search through them and save searches for later use.

If you are using GNOME [here's how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24780/how-to-make-kde-applications-look-native-in-gnome) to make digiKam look native .

Comment: I liked to use digiKam when I was using the KDE desktop a few years ago, it was already very powerful back then, but I am rather picky when it comes to desktop integration, therefore using Picasa under Wine is like using digiKam on a gnome desktop, it just doesn't fit and is designed for another desktop experience. And yes I know that technically there is no problem with running KDE apps on gnome and vice versa.
Anyway I will have to use digikam when other options turn out to be not working for me.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/24780/how-to-make-kde-applications-look-native-in-gnome/24786#24786 it will make your app look absolutely native.

Comment: thanks for the link, this indead lets digiKam fit alot better into the gnome desktop, it's a fiddle with the colors though!
digiKam seems to do its job well, however I will need some more time to see if it fits my needs and more important habits ;)

Comment: if you use maverick's default theme then you can use this color scheme here(http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1682563)

Comment: +1 - Wow, that looks like some very slick software there!

Answer (score 2):

### [Darktable](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/darktable) [image: Install darktable]

In answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22896/how-do-i-print-photos) you will find a good selection of photo managing software in addition to F-Spot. Amongst those suggested I found Darktable to not only look good but also have many useful features when it comes to organize your collection:

[image]

This project is in active development. More recent version can be installed from the official PPA `ppa:pmjdebruijn/darktable-release` .

Answer (score -1):

**[Shotwell](http://yorba.org/shotwell/)** (Included in default)

> Shotwell can import photos and videos from a digital camera directly. Shotwell automatically groups photos and videos by date, and supports tagging. Its image editing features allow users to rotate, crop, eliminate red eye, and adjust levels and color balance. It also features an auto "enhance" option that will attempt to guess appropriate levels for the image. Shotwell allows users to publish their images and videos to Facebook, Flickr, Picasa Web Albums, Piwigo, and YouTube.

Comment: Shotwell disrupts my folder based album when a album contains pictures from different days, that is simply useless for me!

I would have to reoganize everyting when using shotwell, thanks anyway!