# An independently browseable database of large thumbnails?

Tags: browser, shotwell, thumbnails, photo

I've googled about this for a while but to no avail. I have a huge amount of photos stored in several media and backed up in a cloud. Shotwell generates pretty large thumbnails which are quite good for getting an idea of both subject and quality of a photo. The thumbnails are organized in groups based on timestamps and original folders. I'd like to be able to browse a complete collection of the thumbnails even when the program has no access to a complete collection of the real photos (as a matter of fact, I don't have a complete collection of the photos in a single storage device). This would be very convenient to me for several reasons; I could browse them from several PCs with differently named home folders, I could tag them according to their storage location etc. The whole collection of the thumbnails would be reasonably light and I could easily update it with rsync. However, if Shotwell doesn't find the actual photos, it automatically moves the corresponding thumbs under a missing pictures heading and their structure is lost.

I have tried to directly import the thumbs into Shotwell, but the original timestamps and tags are gone. A possible way out would be, to automate a process of thumbnail generation and of folder structure generation based on timestamps, but before getting entangled in that I thought I better ask a question here.
Do you know any tricks or tweaks -- or can you recommend any specific programs -- that would allow me to browse a (huge) collection of thumbnails without having access to the originals? I have a sense that programs of this kind must be in use somewhere but, as I said, I couldn't find out any.
Thanks!

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/31664/photo-manager-that-organises-by-folder-structure - I found Darktable to be quite handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F-Spot is a good tool for image retrieval - though maybe just like Shot well.

I have a version of Ubuntu called Ubuntu Studio along side a normal Ubuntu distro.

With Ubuntu Studio, you have improved catalog of image, sound, and video programs, without forgetting what makes Ubuntu a great OS.

Look into that option - a dual-boot of Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio (unless you want to install Ubuntu Studio into a VirtualBox or via Live-CD to try it out before installing.

You might be pleasantly surprised.

Steve

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at the specs of Ubuntu Studio and took the Tour. The software which comes with US is very good but (i) it doesn't solve my problem; (ii) it's extremely heavy on system resources. As it happens only one of my PCs can (barely) run Darktable. I am interested in a lightweight solution that would allow me to quickly browse my thumbs even from a netbook. -- Thus, I'm afraid I'm going to write my script... If I succeed, I'll post it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem with a script that generates a thumbnail database. ImageMagick must be installed for the script to run. The script requires two arguments specifying a Source photo path and a Target path. It recursively searches Source for JPG files and generates correctly oriented thumbnails with user-defined width and quality (just change JPG to something else if you wish; it handles all the file formats handled by IM). It generates two thumbnail databases:

(1) db in Target: thumbnails are arranged in a YYYY/MM/DD folder structure based on the original EXIF dates.

(2) db in Target.Mirror: thumbs are organized in a folder structure that precisely mirrors the structure of their source.

You can easily change the script to generate just one db. I paste here only the core of the script leaving out path checking and manipulation, arguments handling, echo messages, comments, etc. Source, Target and Mirror paths must have a trailing "/".

```
#!/bin/bash
# The following variables have to be initialized
# Source=<path_to_source/>
# Target=<path_to_target/>
# Mirror=<Target.mirror/>
# Width=<Thumbnail width> (experiment with 368, 416, 512, 1024)
# Quality=<Thumbnail quality> (0% to 100%: 95% is fine, try 75%)

   shopt -s globstar
   cd "$Source"
   for f in **
   do
      if ! ([[ -d "$f" ]]) && ([[ "$f" == *"JPG" ]] || [[ "$f" == *"jpg" ]])
      then
        echo -e "           ${\e[0;32m}" $Source$f${\e[0m}
        Date=$(identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]" $f)
        FolderName="$Target${Date:0:4}/${Date:5:2}/${Date:8:2}"                     
        if ! [[ -d $FolderName ]]
        then
          mkdir -p "$FolderName"
        fi
        Filename="${f##*/}"
        convert "$Source$f" -thumbnail $Width -quality $Quality -auto-orient \
        "$FolderName/$Filename"
 # to preserve profiles such as EXIF data, replace line above with the following:
 #
 # convert "$Source$f" -resize $Width -quality $Quality -auto-orient
 # "$FolderName/$Filename"
 #
 # it takes a bit longer and thumbnails are bigger in size -- profiles use up
 # to 60K
        if ! [[ "${f%/*}" == "$f" ]]
        then
          if ! [[ -d "$Mirror""${f%/*}" ]]
          then
            mkdir -p "$Mirror${f%/*}"
          fi
        fi
        cp "$FolderName/$Filename" "$Mirror$f"
      fi
   done
```

The db is really lightweight (with Width set to 416 and a Quality of 95% the db size is about 1% of the original); copies of it can easily be kept in a notebook or in an android phone and Shotwell browses it lightning fast. If the script is run again with a new source (but with the same target and mirror) the existing dbs are updated.
What can I say -- thank you, Gnu and Linux!