# How do I print a photo on Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, photo, kodak

I want to use glossy photo paper to get a photo printed.  So what I need to do and how do I use this type of paper?

Printer info -

**Kodak ESP c315**

Comment: related:http://askubuntu.com/questions/22896/how-do-i-print-photos Printing depends on the printer driver. What is your printer?

Comment: My printer is Kodak ESP c315,thank you!

Comment: Can you use Gimp ?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to make use of features your printer offers you will have to download and install an appropriate driver. Sadly Kodak does not make any Linux drivers.

There is a sourceforge project that offers drivers for Kodak printers:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/

There you will also find Debian packages including packages for 64-bit Ubuntu for installation. However I have no idea if they install and run nicely, and to what extent your printer will be supported.

Sadly in the usual case (of many other printers) we see that the drivers offered are way behind their proprietary Windows counterparts both in comfort, and in printing quality.

Answer (score 0):

You print just like on other OSes. In your printer settings, set the kind of paper to "Photo paper" (or something like this, it depends on your printer). For using it, you have to print on the glossy side of your photo paper.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this but when I went on settings,the paper type sittings is not available.

Comment: What is your printer model ? I don't know for other printers but for HP printers, it is referred as "Media Type". Perhaps it is the same thing on Kodak printers.

Comment: My printer model is Kodak ESP c315